# Symfony - Creating complex queries using Doctrine

Tags: jquery, symfony, doctrine, where-clause, query-builder

What is the best way to create more complex queries using Doctrine in Symfony? For instance, I need query that would have 3 parameters, two AND and one nested OR condition. In mySQL it would look something like this:

```
        SELECT *
        FROM schedule sched
        WHERE shed.date = '01-01-2018'  --first parameter
        AND (sched.timefrom BETWEEN 8 AND 12   -- second and third parameter
        OR sched.timeto BETWEEN 8 AND 12)      -- also second and third
```

I tried in number of ways but nothing works:

```
  $query = $em->createQuery(
        'SELECT sched
         FROM schedule sched
         WHERE shed.date = :d
         AND (sched.timefrom BETWEEN :tf AND :tt
         OR sched.timeto BETWEEN :tf AND :tt)'
       ) ->setParameters(['d' => $date->format('Y-m-d'), 'tf' => $timefrom, 'tt' => $timeto]);
```

this did not work even if I replaced BETWEEN With full condition, like this:

```
     (sched.timefrom > :tf AND sched.timefrom < :tt)
```

Using QueryBuilder also did not work and I tried in several ways, this was the last one (also tried with expressionBuilder, did not work either):

```
      $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(schedule::Class);
      $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('sched');
      $query->where('sched.date = :date AND ((sched.timefrom > :timefrom AND sched.timefrom < :timeto) OR (shced.timeto > :timefrom AND sched.timeto < :timeto))')
      ->setParameter('date', $date->format('Y-m-d'))
      ->setParameter('tf', $timefrom)
      ->setParameter('tt', $timeto);
       $query = $query->getQuery();
```

also:

```
      $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(schedule::Class);
      $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('sched');
      $query->where('sched.date = :date')
      ->andWhere('sched.timefrom > :timefrom AND sched.timefrom < :timeto') 
      ->orwhere('sched.timeto > :timefrom AND sched.timeto < :timeto')
      ->setParameter('date', $date->format('Y-m-d'))
      ->setParameter('tf', $timefrom)
      ->setParameter('tt', $timeto);
       $query = $query->getQuery();
```

How do you create query that has many ORs and ANDs and some brackets too?
Thanks!

Comment: what did you tried with the expressionBuilder?  i think the expression builder is really strong and can handle you problems. show me your code may i canhelp you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you look for something like that?

```
  $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(schedule::Class);
    $q = $repository->createQueryBuilder('sched');
    $expr = $q->expr();

    $exprQuery =
        $expr->andX(
            $expr->eq('sched.date',$date-format('Y-m-d')),
            $expr->orX(
                $expr->between('sched.timefrom',$timefrom,$timeto),
                $expr->between('sched.timeto',$timefrom,$timeto)
            )
        );

    $q->where($exprQuery);
    $q = $q->getQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with first version is the query

```
(sched.timefrom BETWEEN :tf AND :tt
     OR sched.timeto BETWEEN :tf AND :tt)
```

should be

```
((sched.timefrom BETWEEN :tf AND :tt)
     OR (sched.timeto BETWEEN :tf AND :tt))
```

The main problem with second and third versions is setting parameters because in query you used `:timefrom` and `:timeto` but setting `tf` and `tt`. I prefer using `BETWEEN`. That is

```
$query->where('sched.date = :date AND ((sched.timefrom > :timefrom AND sched.timefrom < :timeto) 
               OR (shced.timeto > :timefrom AND sched.timeto < :timeto))')
  ->setParameter('date', $date->format('Y-m-d'))
  ->setParameter('tf', $timefrom)
  ->setParameter('tt', $timeto);
```

should be

```
$query->where('sched.date = :date AND ((sched.timefrom BETWEEN :timefrom AND :timeto) 
              OR (shced.timeto BETWEEN :timefrom AND :timeto))')
  ->setParameter('date', $date->format('Y-m-d'))
  ->setParameter('timefrom', $timefrom)
  ->setParameter('timeto', $timeto);
```

Try this. I hope it helps!

```
  $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(schedule::Class);

  $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('sched')
  ->where('sched.date = :date')
  ->andWhere('(sched.timefrom BETWEEN :timefrom AND :timeto) 
              OR (sched.timeto BETWEEN :timefrom AND :timeto)')
  ->setParameter('date', $date->format('Y-m-d'))
  ->setParameter('timefrom', $timefrom)
  ->setParameter('timeto', $timeto);
   $query = $query->getQuery();
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! What did I do wrong? This looks similar to one of my queries but mine does not work and yours does.

Comment: @BiljanaM. I updated the answer. Please [accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to help others. Thanks!